# Find a complete integral for $uu_xu_y = u_x + u_y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Find a complete integral for $uu_xu_y = u_x + u_y$.

- We have $F(p,q,z,x,y) := zpq - p - q = 0$, where $p = u_x, q = u_y,$ and $z = u$. Using Charpit's method, we get
  $$\frac{dx}{zq -1} = \frac{dy}{zp - 1} = \frac{dz}{2zpq - p -q} = \frac{dp}{-p^2q} = \frac{dq}{-pq^2}$$
  The last equality gives $$p = c_1q$$ for some constant $c_1$. Beyond this point, I find myself stuck. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $p=c_1q$ into the original PDE to find that
\begin{align}
p=\frac{1+c_1}{u}\quad \text{and}\quad q=\frac{1+c_1}{c_1u}.
\end{align}
Via the chain rule we know that $\mathrm du=p\mathrm dx+q\mathrm dy$, so substituting and integrating we arrive at the complete integral

\begin{align}
\mathrm du=\frac{1+c_1}{u}\mathrm dx+\frac{1+c_1}{c_1u}\mathrm dy,\quad\longrightarrow\quad
u^2=2(1+c_1)x+2(1+\frac{1}{c_1})y+c_0.
\end{align}

Comment: That's pretty neat! Thanks.